# MYSQL not returning all rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get the results from the database of the whole year.

This is the query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(tickets_replay.id) AS amount, users.name,
  MONTHNAME(tickets_replay.created) AS month 
    FROM `tickets_replay` INNER
    JOIN users ON tickets_replay.user_id = users.id 
      WHERE tickets_replay.`created` LIKE '2018%' 
        AND tickets_replay.`deleted` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        AND tickets_replay.comment NOT LIKE
         'Uitvoerdatum aangepast naar:%' 
        AND tickets_replay.comment NOT LIKE
         'Status is aangepast naar:%' 
        AND users.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        AND users.id = 21 GROUP BY MONTH(tickets_replay.created)
```

In my PhpMyAdmin I'm getting this:

[image]

And in my code I get this back:

[image]

PHP code:

```
$sql_dylan = "
SELECT COUNT(tickets_replay.id) AS amount, users.name,
  MONTHNAME(tickets_replay.created) AS month 
    FROM `tickets_replay` INNER
    JOIN users ON tickets_replay.user_id = users.id 
      WHERE tickets_replay.`created` LIKE '2018%' 
        AND tickets_replay.`deleted` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        AND tickets_replay.comment NOT LIKE
         'Uitvoerdatum aangepast naar:%' 
        AND tickets_replay.comment NOT LIKE
         'Status is aangepast naar:%' 
        AND users.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        AND users.id = 21 GROUP BY MONTH(tickets_replay.created)
";

if ($results_dylan = mysqli_query($sql_connect, $sql_dylan)){
    while($rows_dylan = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results_dylan)) {
        printr($rows_dylan, false);
    }
}


function printr($data, $exit = TRUE)
{
    if ($data) {
        print '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
        print '</pre>';
    }
    if ($exit) {
        exit;
    }
}
```

I'm using the exact same query and all but I'm not getting all the results.
How can I change that?

Comment: This is tagged as "php"; have you the code for it and how you're looping?

Comment: @Gufran your edit should be re-edited. Don't use `>` here.

Comment: Could you please copy the text instead of an image?

Comment: Do you have a limit on the loop in your PHP code handling the select? Maybe you could show the PHP code as well...

Comment: The `>` should all be removed in the previous edit here. It is defacing the query with special characters.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, Thanks, next time I will keep it in mind :)

Comment: `printr` is that a typo? That should read as `print_r()` and you're already using a `while` loop.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thats a custom function

Comment: The values in the two arrays are different (check `April` and `March`). I suggest you look in your MySQL connection and/or PHP error logs.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question but are you sure that the database you connect at with your SQL client is the same as the one your Php code connects at?

Comment: I was just going to say the same as Luk. If the queries are identical but produce different results then the most likely cause is that phpmyAdmin and PHP are looking two different copies of the database

Comment: P.S. `tickets_replay.\`created\` LIKE '2018%'` worries me, it suggests potentially you are storing dates as strings, which is a big no-no. The `datetime` type exists for a reason...use it. If you changed your column to a proper datetime, you could then use `YEAR(tickets_replay.\`created\`) = '2018'` to get the same result as this current statement

Comment: @ADyson yeah and OP has zero (`0000-00-00`) value datetimes as well which should not be in a *proper* database

Comment: Btw, perhaps users.name should be included in the GROUP BY.  I know MySql is kinda tollerant about missing unaggregated fields in the GROUP BY, but at least it would make the SQL more ANSI SQL complaint.

Comment: Also, fields can be nullable. Don’t store “0000-00-00 00:00:00” to mean that it’s not deleted. Just leave the field NULL and query `WHERE users.deleted IS NULL`.

Comment: @Martin true although mysql does actually support that even in proper date columns, interestingly.

Comment: @LukStorms and that as well, when this gets run on MySQL 5.7 all sorts of fails will occur....

Comment: @ADyson true, but only upto 5.7 and only beyond 5.7 by manually forcing it ....

Comment: @xQbert I only want to get the results of that user

Comment: @xQbert When i'm using user.id = 29 i'm getting this back
https://imgur.com/a/jcEroel

Comment: @StanvanHeertum that screenshot doesn't mean anything. We have nothing to compare it to

Comment: I was using the wrong server, but thanks for all the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer:

The reason you are getting different results is because you are testing against different sets of data.

How do we know this?

Look at `March` and `April` in your screenshots from the two locations.

**Your PHPMyAdmin:**

[image]

**Your PHP Code:**

[image]

This shows that because the SQL is **exactly the same**, that the data *must* be different.

So, double check your MySQL connection is connecting to the correct table on the correct database.